# only id_rsa.pub key working on Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, apache-http-server

**Hi everyone,**
I haven a new Linux server but when I want to connect with SSH, I can only use my id_rsa.pub key. I tried making other .pub keys (instead of the id_rsa.pub) but it keeps asking a password when I want to use other keys. Am I missing something here?

**I have tried:**
Editing the permission of my .ssh folder because it seems like a common problem, but it was already set to the correct permission.

Here is the code to make a key and copy it to my server:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@email.com" 


ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/test.pub user@myLinuxServer
```

I can find the key on my server in the authorized_keys file so I think copying is not a problem.

**I expect:**
that I can login without giving a password when I type:

```
 Ssh user@host
```

in the terminal, but it still asks for a password. Only when I use ssh-copy-id on the id_rsa.pub key, it will work.

Comment: You can use `ssh -vv user@host` to see in more deail the login process, when is tried and what is not.

Comment: look at your ~/.ssh/config for that host

Comment: @linuxdev2013 I don't have ~/.ssh/config file.. only known_hosts but is the same innit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy you public key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

AFAIK  `authorized_key` is not a directory.

You can read this [article](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/)

Comment: My bad, I meant authorized_keys file, not folder ... :)

Comment: @aaronlejeune is your problem solved?

Comment: yes it worked, sorry for the late answer